# NFSv4 wrong effective user / owner, sec=krb5 mount squashes to anonymous user

Tags: linux, kerberos, nfsv4

I'm setting up kerberized NFSv4 for personal use

- manually configured NFS, KDC
- no nameservers (using `/etc/hosts` instead), no LDAP
- same users on all machines (not necessarily the same id) and using id mapping for all security modes
  (`nfs4_disable_idmapping` set to 'N')

I've got two machines, both running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

- `arhiv.pecar` (local address `192.168.56.200`) has the NFS server and the KDC
- `client.pecar` (local address `192.158.56.100`) is the client

---

All plumbing seems to work and I can mount the share just fine, but

- if the share is exported with `sec=sys`

  server `exportfs -v` output

  ```
  /srv/export     <world>(rw,async,wdelay,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
  ```

  client `mount` output

  ```
  arhiv.pecar:/srv/export on /mnt type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=krb5,clientaddr=192.168.56.100,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.56.200)
  ```

  - root has full read / write access
  - other users can read / write files if sufficient privileges are set up
  - `nfsidmap` is active, listing files on the client **properly translates** usernames / groups
  - `chown` from client is **possible**, and properly translates usernames / groups

  Files are created under the uid/gid of the **client**, which means they are created with the **wrong** uid / gid on the server

  It gets mapped to the wrong owner if the server happens to have a user with the same uid, otherwise the owner is `nobody:4294967294`

  The effective user seems to be user specified by the clients uid.

  I suppose this is a [known drawback](http://dfusion.com.au/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=Why%20NFSv4%20UID%20mapping%20breaks%20with%20AUTH_UNIX) when using `sec=sys`
- if the share is exported with `sec=krb5`

  server `exportfs -v` output

  ```
  /srv/export     <world>(rw,async,wdelay,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5p:krb5,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
  ```

  client `mount` output

  ```
  arhiv.pecar:/srv/export on /mnt type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.56.100,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.56.200)
  ```

  - all users have read access, no user (including root) has write access on files / folders owned by them
  - creating files in `o+w` folders will create them under the anonymous user (`nobody:nogroup` or `anonuid:anongid` if specified in exports entry)
  - `nfsidmap` is active, listing files on the client **properly translates** usernames / groups
  - `chown` from client **fails** with `Operation not permitted.`

  The effective user seems to be the anonymous user.

I'm at a loss on what could be wrong here, so I'd appreciate the communities insight.

I can provide the relevant configuration files (`/etc/hosts`, `/etc/krb5.conf`, `/etc/idmapd.conf`, `/etc/default/nfs-common`, service, kernel module list) upon request.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I've figured out that it's worthwhile to understand *how* NFS and Kerberos deal with users, and how principal names come to play here - topics that are frequently left out in most guides.

---

In kerberized NFS, one needs to be aware of the difference between

- **the effective user executing the file operation**

  The effective (server-local) user of the file operation is determined by Kerberos' [local authorization interface](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/plugindev/localauth.html), which is [configured via `auth_to_local` tag](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#realms), and if none given, defaults to `auth_to_local = DEFAULT`, the operation for which is defined as

  > The principal name will be used as the local user name. If the principal has more than one component or is not in the default realm, this rule is not applicable and the conversion will fail.

  In the case of conversion failure it assumes the anonymous user (`nobody:nogroup` or `anonuid:anongid` if specified in exports entry)

  [Related discussion that provides a good explanation.](https://docs.pagure.org/sssd.sssd/design_pages/nss_with_kerberos_principal.html)
- **the parameters / results of this file operation**

  When the NFS server performs the file operation

  1. parameters need to be mapped from client-provided users to server-local users (`chown` command)
  2. results need to be mapped back to client-local users (`ls` command)

  This is handled by the `id_resolver` upcall program specified in `/etc/request-key.conf` or `/etc/request-key.d/*` (usually `nfsidmap`).

  Usernames are transferred between hosts as `user@dns_domain` strings and are mapped to local uid/gid on each side.

The effective user performing the file operation is derived from the ticket (thus it matters under which principal we authentecate), and *NOT* from the uid of the locally running process requesting the file operation (which one might naively expect).

---

So, in order for the effective user mapping to work, one needs to create a `username` principal (effectively `username@REALM`) or, if a more complex principal name is used, provide an appropriate `auth_to_local` mapping in `/etc/krb5.conf`, as described here

- https://access.redhat.com/articles/4040141
- https://blog.samoylenko.me/2015/04/15/hadoop-security-auth_to_local-examples/
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Auth-to-local-Rules-Syntax/ta-p/245316

---

Each user *should have its own* default principal (`user/client-fqdn`), which is used for mapping to server-local user.

Service principals are used & authorized by the services themselves and presumably there is no need for users to have access to them (they should be retained in `/etc/krb5.keytab` but not in user keytabs)

User keytab locaton varies between distributions - use `krb5-config` to figure out what is expected by your build

```bsh
USER_KEYTAB=$(euid=$EUID; eval echo $(krb5-config --defcktname | tr % $ | sed 's/FILE://'))
```

---

Below is quick demo on how to properly configure mapping for a user over kerberized NFS.

The following configuration was tested on CentOS systems configured via this guide (guide intended for Centos 7, tested on 8, minor additions were needed)

https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-set-up-nfs-server-with-kerberos-based-authentication

```bsh
# Start kadmin on client machine (I assume that you have the root/admin principal already set up)
#
[root@nfsclient ~]# kadmin -p root/admin
Authenticating as principal root/admin with password.
Password for root/admin@KDC.COM: 

kadmin:  addprinc -randkey -clearpolicy host/nfsclient
Principal "host/nfsclient@KDC.COM" created.

kadmin:  addprinc -randkey -clearpolicy nfs/nfsclient
Principal "nfs/nfsclient@KDC.COM" created.

kadmin:  ktadd -k /tmp/krb5.keytab host/nfsclient
Entry for principal host/nfsclient with kvno 2, encryption type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 added to keytab WRFILE:/tmp/krb5.keytab.
...

kadmin:  ktadd -k /tmp/krb5.keytab nfs/nfsclient
Entry for principal nfs/nfsclient with kvno 2, encryption type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 added to keytab WRFILE:/tmp/krb5.keytab.
...

kadmin:  addprinc -randkey -clearpolicy testuser
Principal "testuser@KDC.COM" created.

kadmin:  ktadd -k /tmp/client.keytab testuser
Entry for principal testuser with kvno 2, encryption type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 added to keytab WRFILE:/tmp/client.keytab.
...

kadmin:  quit


# Set up the default keytab (service principals)
[root@nfsclient ~]# mv /tmp/krb5.keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
[root@nfsclient ~]# chown root:root /etc/krb5.keytab

# Set up user keytab
[root@nfsclient ~]# mv /tmp/client.keytab /var/kerberos/krb5/user/$(id -u testuser)/client.keytab
[root@nfsclient ~]# chown testuser:testuser /var/kerberos/krb5/user/$(id -u testuser)/client.keytab

# Mount the filesystem
mount nfsserver.kdc.com:/kerberos /mnt

# Test the user
[root@nfsclient ~]# sudo -i -u testuser

# Check that the users client.keytab, is being picked up
# (can access nfs share)
#
# and that the correct effective user is now used for file operation
# (derived from default principal and mapped to server-local user)
# - the server should also have a `testuser` user
#
[testuser@nfsclient ~]$ touch /mnt/testfile
[testuser@nfsclient ~]$ ls -la /mnt/testfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 testuser testuser 0 Jun 23 16:31 /mnt/testfile

# After accesses one can check the keys that have been retrieved on 
[testuser@nfsclient ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: KCM:1051:17737
Default principal: testuser@KDC.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/23/2021 16:06:12  06/24/2021 16:06:12  krbtgt/KDC.COM@KDC.COM
        renew until 06/23/2021 16:06:12
06/23/2021 16:06:12  06/24/2021 16:06:12  nfs/nfsserver.kdc.com@KDC.COM
        renew until 06/23/2021 16:06:12
```

Comment: I got additional remarks at https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/o1v8hb/kerberized_nfs_how_to_properly_handle_user_mapping/

do check them. When I'll be comfortable that I understand them, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes for this might be, for those authenticating with *winbind*, is the samba (smb.conf) configuration of `winbind use default domain = no`.

This default configuration makes authentication expect user names to appear with the `DOMAIN\` prefix (ex: `DOMAIN\alice`).

See: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#winbindusedefaultdomain

You should configure this parameter to `yes` (in both client and server) in order to be able to login simply as `su - alice` and not as `su - DOMAIN\\alice`.

The names nfs server will compare against kerberos tickets will be the shorter one. With the default longer version, gss fails to find the user and so squashes it to be "nobody".

As for the answer of [@tpecar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/477591/tpecar) : Myself, I got the client keytab created properly with a simple `kinit` call by the user. Didn't need anything else.